# Append square brackets right after a code block

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i wonder how i can append the `[]` (string) right after a function call

something like

```
@Html.ActionLink("x", "y")[]
```

I have tried this but it results in compile error since the bracket is consider as an index operator

i want the html result to be like

```
<a ....>...</a>[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parentheses to specify what's in the expression:

```
@(Html.ActionLink("x", "y"))[]
```